# Oracle composite index with not all fields in condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Tell me please a little about Oracle indexes, because I don't know how to ask about this situation to Google. Let's pretend I have a table

```
table T (
    Id key
    FKey1 int,
    FKey2 int,
    Date1 date,
    Date2 date,
    Name string,
    Surname string
)
```

And have a composite index on all this fields except Id. I have 2 queries which used:

1. All the columns except Name and Surname;
2. All the columns except Surname - and search for Name with LIKE expression.

Is this index efficient? And if not, how can I improve it? Queries generated by ORM and just have a possibility to use indexes :(

Real index columns sequence:

```
Name
Surname
FKey1
FKey2
Date1
Date2
```

Comment: show your exact index column sequence

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the sequence of the columns declared in the creation of the index .. it is important that the columns are more selettiv or used in all the queries are placed  before the others: in your case

```
....

Surname ,  Name    //used by two user queries
```

work better than

```
Name , surname // //used by oneuser queries
```

Comment: And what if I don't use all columns in WHERE statement which in index?

Comment: if you do not use all the columns, the rules of the most selective columns are always valid. for this reason it is advisable to evaluate the most used queries and create the indexes using the most used column for first to ecosi via. SI create different indexes (and requires the queries to use specific indexes for this, and this is also why the queries generated automatically by ORM or framework are often not efficient)

Comment: so the best way is to have an index for each case, but if I have an index for full set of fields and don't use 'em all - it's ok ?

Comment: NO the best is not an index  for each case  .. the best is the minum number of index  for the most relevant and slow queries ..  .. with a proper analisys of the query often  a reduced  set of indexes  is enough .

Comment: yes. I understand this. But I don't know how much and what queries will be generated by ORM, so I just react if something bad happen. That's why I ask about if the index with fields for case 2 from topic will cover case 1 (with less fields in WHERE)

Comment: The problem with ORM is ofetn this  .. sometimes in mission critical application .. is necessary .. bypass the queries  generated  by ORM and use raw query with index usage forced  by programmers .. but this is only for heavy application  ..  +

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162424/discussion-between-r1k0-and-scaisedge).

Comment: @scaisEdge - I'm guessing "colinas" are columns, but what are "venganio queries"?